# how to use cookies in jsp/servlet using IBM web sphere 8.5 with RAD

Tags: servlets, cookies

currently i am making a web application using jsp and servlet

i am using cookies in it for saving login information

now my problem is that when i am running same code using eclipse and tomcat its works perfactly but when i am running on IBM Rational Application Developer and WebSphere Application Server 8.5 application is running but cookies are not stored in browser

so i want to store cookies in browser using websphere
so please help me for this issue

is there a any configuration in websphere for cookies ??

Comment: So you're creating a custom cookie and setting that with the HttpServletResponse, and that cookie is not sent back in a Set-Cookie response header? Or it's sent back in a Set-Cookie response header, but it's not being returned in the subsequent browser request?

Comment: yaa i am creating custom cookie and send with response.addcookie() method after that when i am find cookies in my browser i cant find any cookie in my browser it means cookies are added in response

Comment: There is nothing special you have to do to get this to work in WebSphere. It certainly works for me in WebSphere + RAD. Can you look at the HTTP Response headers (like with a browser plugin) and see that the Set-Cookie header is there? My best guess would be a domain that isn't allowing the cookie to be returned or a switch from http to https.

Comment: It would be good if you could explain, in an Answer, what the problem was. And accept that Answer. So people who search in the future can see it. Or if you feel like it was embarrassing user error :-), you could remove the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that i seted  max age of cookie is 60*60*60*24*365 by mistake
so may be it would overflow of value so cookies are not saved in browser 
now i set value of setmaxage() is 1 year and its worked perfactly

Comment: if you could post code on the correct way to do this I would upvote this and the question